# Implementing Location Protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I Liked the concept of Protocol Oriented Programming and I am trying to start writing protocols by Protocol Extensions in swift.

I am trying to bring device location using Protocol Extensions.

However I am facing problems on creating that as the following:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

protocol Locator:CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
{ get set }

var locationHandler: ((CLLocation)->())?
{ get set }

func getLocation(completionHandler:@escaping (CLLocation)->())
}

extension Locator {

    private var _locationManager:CLLocationManager {
        get {return self.locationManager} set {self.locationManager = newValue}
    }

    private var _locationHandler:((CLLocation)->())? {
        get {return self.locationHandler} set {self.locationHandler = newValue}
    }

    func getLocation(completionHandler:@escaping (CLLocation)->()) {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            return
        case .denied, .restricted:
            return
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
        self.locationHandler = completionHandler

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways  {
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Hey this is a location")
        if let currentLocation = locations.last {
            self._locationHandler?(currentLocation)
        }
    }


}
```

However the completion handler is not working properly.

what is my problem and How can I proceed creating this in Protocols concept.

Comment: Can you define "not working properly"?

Comment: It is not executing the completion handler block